# When do I differentiate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I know how to differentiate, for example if I get a question like: *'Differentiate the following':

However, how do I know WHEN to differentiate when it is in an application question.  For example the below:

The function $y = x^2 + ax^2 + 9x - 3$  has a stationary point when $x=1$.  Find the value of  a and determine the nature of this stationary point.

So according to the mark scheme, I need to differentiate.  Why?  And HOW do I know whatever question I get when I need to differentiate, or if I need to do it at all?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is explicitly referring to a specific function having a stationary point at $x=1$.  The very definition of stationary point is that the derivative of the function is equal to $0$ at that point.  So it is obvious that a reasonable way to apply that information is to look at the derivative and try to figure out what needs to happen for it to be $0$ at $x=1$.  It seems more likely that you don't know what a stationary point is than that you don't know when to use derivatives.

Comment: I think you should study "application of derivatives", so you will know what is use of "differentiation" and when and why to use it!

Answer (score 2):

Differentiation is usually the way to go when you are aked to devise characteristics of a given function. The first derivative gives you information about the monotonicity at each point (whether the curve, when plotted, goes up and down), and the second derivative gives information about the curvature of the function at every point (if it is concave or convex). Therefore, the easiest way of dealing with problems related to these characterisitcs of the function is usually differentiating the amount of times needed and analysing the resulting function.

For instance, in the problem you have, stationary points are those in which the function neither increases nor decreases in a small neighborhood around. Since this is a question about the monotonicity of the function, the way to find those points in which the function has stationary points is differentiating twice and looking for the $x$ that satisfy $y'(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

So it is stationary at point $x=1$, meaning that the gradient at $x=1$ is 0.
So then we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ at $x=1$. Differentiating the equation gives the gradient of the function at particular points.

$$x^2+ax^2+9x-3=(1+a)x^2+9x-3$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2(1+a)x+9$$

Can you carry on from here?

Comment: Hi @Kenny thanks so much.  I know how to do the question, I was just wondering WHEN I need to differentiate.  i.e when do I have to do it / when do I not do it?  Thanks!

Comment: Differentiate when you find the question that requests for stationary points at particular points. Differentiation deals with gradient and change. Example: $Velocity=\frac{ds}{dt}$ where $s=displacement$ because velocity is change in displacement with respect to time.