# Practical procedure for functions analysis

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

I need to declare if the function $e^{-x} (2x + 1)$ is one of the followings options (thanks!)

- convex for: $ x \le \frac{3}{2} $
- decreasing for: $ x \le \frac{1}{2} $
- concave for: $ x \ge \frac{3}{2} $
- increasing for: $ x \le \frac{1}{2} $

I used SageMath and Jupyter and plotting the function the answer seems clear. Because I have to prepare an exam I would like ask to you guys some questions:

1. To do it manually without programming should I draw the graph calculating the result of the function?
2. Home many point should I take? 2, 3, more?
3. For calculating the result shoud I consider an aproximation of $e$ like 2.71...?

## x <= 3/2

[image]

[image]

## x <= 1/2

[image]

## x >= 3/2

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I differentiate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779201/when-do-i-differentiate)

Answer (score 1):

Graph is not a good way to study differentiable functions, usually we need to consider and study the sign of their derivatives.

In this case, the first derivative is

$$f(x)= e^{-x} (2x + 1)\implies f'(x)=e^{-x} (1-2x)$$

and then we need to study its sign to determine in which interval the function is increasing ($f'(x) \ge 0$) and in which interval it is decreasing ($f'(x) \le 0$).

For the [convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) of a differentiable function we can consider the sign of the second derivative

$$f(x)= e^{-x} (2x + 1)\implies f''(x)=e^{-x} (2x -3)\ge 0 \implies 2x-3\ge 0$$

that is $x\ge \frac 32$.